# Dependency not instalable

Tags: 20.04

I tried to install a package,
I use Ubuntu 20.04 arm64,
The package in question is ...  Mongo databasetools And when I execute …
apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-arm64-100.6.1.deb
I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-database-tools:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libkrb5-3:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libk5crypto3:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libcomerr2:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libkrb5support0:arm64 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libkeyutils1:arm64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

All of these packages are ‘Ubuntu key packages’, so I tried to update them … but it’s not possible to remove them (can harm Ubuntu … the system warn about the comand `sudo apt remove libc6`)
I have also tried to run it in a Docker container (Ubuntu & Debian, it fails too …)
I have followed the following tutorial [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) ... but None of these actions helped me

Comment: Where did you get the package from?

Comment: Apt is trying to tell you that the package+version is utterly incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. One possible solution might be to try a version of that package that is compatible. Another possible solution is to revisit why you want to install that package -- whatever problem you have the led you to that package as a solution, perhaps a different approach to that problem might be more successful.

Comment: This method of installation comes from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/
By the meantime my manager came with the idea of install `mongo-tools` instead of `mongo-database-tools`. After removing the old not working `/usr/bin/mongodump` & `/usr/bin/mongorestore` I reinstall simply via `sudo apt reinstall mongo-tools` https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/mongodb-tools